# Visual Studio Drawimage drag and drop image

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I want to know how i can move a image that i create with System.DrawImage() with mouse. I try with this but dont work:

```
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

    if (rectA.Contains(mousePt))
    {
        isImageClicked = false;
    }

}

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    if (rectA.Contains(mousePt))
    {
        isImageClicked = true;
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    if (rectA.Contains(mousePt) && isImageClicked)
    {
        rectA.X = mousePt.X;
        rectA.Y = mousePt.Y;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I think that have some way to refresh that, but i dont know!

Comment: I think that your check in Form1_MouseMove for (rect.Contains(mousePt)) may be detrimental. If they click on the top left corner and move the mouse up or left then the mouse no longer resides within rectA and rectA will not be moved. I would start with removing that check. Also since you don't record your initial offset within the rectA know that it's position will pop so the top-left corner is aligned with the mouse pointer.

Comment: I see nothing in your code that relates to an image. Where should the image reside in? In a Control, like panel.BackgroundImage or is it drawn onto a control or the form with Graphics.DrawImage? For the latter use the Paint event to draw to a class level point and the mousemove to move the point while the left mousebutton is pressed and to Invalidate the control/form to show the new position! - If the latter is true, do show the Paint event! - Also: Get rid of the flag and test for e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left) instead!

Comment: Sorry! the code of image draw:

`protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bitmap.FromFile(@"c:\massas\fotos\221.png"), rectA);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bitmap.FromFile(@"c:\massas\fotos\2121.png"), rectB);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }`
I did, but the images blink when I move the mouse